# Refer to hidden type ID in controller page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, hidden

I need to use `hdNoOfColumns` and `hdNoOfRows` in a controller page which are defined as hidden type in View page. I am getting a "context does not exist" error. How do refer to a hidden type ID in the controller page?

View:

```
<input id="hdNoOfRows" type="hidden" name="hdNoOfRows" />
<input id="hdNoOfColumns" type="hidden" name="hdNoOfColumns"/>
```

Controller:

```
hdNoOfColumns.Value = count.ToString();
dsCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
hdNoOfRows.Value = dsCount.ToString();
seatCount = dsS.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

asp.net mvc does not work as asp.net web forms, you need to create a model and then use it:

First Create a Model:

```
public class TableModel
{
  public string NoOfColumns { get; set;}
  public string NoOfRows { get;set; }
}
```

Now in your controller action:

```
public class BarController : Controller
{

   public ActionResult Foo()
   {
     TableModel model = new TableModel();

     model.NoOfColumns= count.ToString();
     dsCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
     model.NoOfRows= dsCount.ToString();
     seatCount = dsS.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    return View(model);
   }
}
```

Now in your View use `HiddenFor()` :

```
@model TableModel


@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.NoOfColumns)
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.NoOfRows)
```

post them by putting them inside form :

and For posting back values to controller you will have to put them  in a form:

```
@model TableModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("Foo", "Bar", FormMethod.Post))
{
<input id="hdNoOfRows" type="hidden" name="hdNoOfRows" />
<input id="hdNoOfColumns" type="hidden" name="hdNoOfColumns"/>
<input type="submit" value="Post"/>
}
```

and then in your controller controller handle in post action of it:

```
public class BarController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
      TableModel model = new TableModel();

      model.NoOfColumns= count.ToString();
      dsCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
      model.NoOfRows= dsCount.ToString();
      seatCount = dsS.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

     return View(model);
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Foo(TableModel model)
   {
      // do saving in db or whatever business logic

      return View(model);
   }

}
```

Comment: @user3793029 you are welcome, start with simple asp.net mvc articles or tutorials to get more clarity

Comment: controller function mentioned here need to write in void function and i am calling this void function in another Index Actionresult method. Index view  already referred another model called allocation model and hence i am not able to use viewmodel as reference in view page

Comment: @user3793029 it depends on your scenarion but normally our action return type is always ``ActionResult`` or its dervied type

Comment: Parent model doesn't worked out. It shows me that model does not contain definition for all variable defined in both model